# Adding jQuery event handler to expand div when a link is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, event-handling, toggle

I'm using a bit of jQuery to expand/hide some divs. I need to add an event handler so that when a link is clicked, it opens a corrisponding div. Each toggled div will have a unique class assigned to it. I am looking for some advice about how to build the event handler.

The jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".toggle_container:not(:first)").hide(); 
$(".toggle_container:first").show();
$("h6.trigger:first").addClass("active");

$("h6.trigger").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  $(this).next(".toggle_container").slideToggle(300);
});
```

The css:

```
// uses a background image with an on (+) and off (-) state stacked on top of each other 
h6.trigger { background: url(buttonBG.gif) no-repeat;height: 46px;line-height: 46px;width: 300px;font-size: 2em;font-weight: normal;} 
h6.trigger a {color: #fff;text-decoration: none; display: block;} 
h6.active {background-position: left bottom;} 
.toggle_container { overflow: hidden; } 
.toggle_container .block {padding: 20px;}
```

The html has a list of links, such as:

```
<a href="#">One</a>
<a href="#">Two</a>
```

and the coorisponding divs to open:

```
<h6 class="trigger">Container one</h6> 
<div class="toggle_container">
div one
</div>

<h6 class="trigger">Container two</h6> 
<div class="toggle_container Open">
div one
</div>
```

As I mentioned, I will be assigning a unique class to facilitate this.

Any advice?  Thanks!

- To clarify, i'm looking for some advice to build an event handler to toggle open a specific div when a link is clicked from a different part of the page, from a nav for instance.

Comment: Your code looks fine.  Are you asking a question?

Comment: Using `$("div.toggle_container").hide().first().show()` instead of `$(".toggle_container:not(:first)").hide(); $(".toggle_container:first").show();` will shave about 0.00001ms off execution time... If I'm being extremely picky :)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, probably not being clear (brain fried).  I've updated my question to be more clear.  The code above works great when the <h6> is clicked.  What I'd like to figure out how to do is to assign another class to this div toggler and trigger it's opening from a link somewhere else on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would lay out your elements like this: (preferring to use an ID instead of a unique class)

```
<a class="toggler" href="#div1">Click</div>
<a class="toggler" href="#div2">Click</div>
<div class="toggle-container" id="div1">
 Hello
</div>
<div class="toggle-container" id="div2">
 Hello
</div>
```

Then the JS would be:

```
$('div.toggle-container').hide().first().show().addClass('active');
$('a.toggler').bind('click', function (e) {
   var href = $(this).attr('href');
   $('div.active').hide().removeClass('active');
   $(href.slice(href.indexOf("#"))).show().addClass('active');

   event.preventDefault();
});
```

If you definitely want to use a unique class, modify the selector as such:

```
$("." + href.slice(href.indexOf("#") + 1)).show().addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger the click event for a specific header like this:

```
<h6 class="trigger" id="myHeader">Container two</h6> 
<div class="toggle_container Open">
div one
</div>


$('#myHeader').click();
```

This will hide the container if it's already open; to prevent that, change it to

```
$('#myHeader:not(.active)').click();
```

(If the header is already `.active`, the selector won't match any elements and nothing will happen)

Comment: I'm not following how $('#myHeader').click(); is assigned to the link?  In other words, how is this function made unique for multiple different links/divs? Thanks!

Comment: @hollyb: `myHeader` is the ID of the specific header `<h6>` that you want to toggle.  Each header should have a unique ID.  (You could also use a class instead)

Comment: OK, sorry but I still don't understand how this can be applied to multiple links/headers.  Say i have 10 different hidden divs and 10 links that when clicked open up a coorisponding div.  Would your method acheive this?  Thanks (and sorry, my jQuery is a bit lacking)

Comment: Give each header a unique ID, and call `$('#idOfHeader').click();` in the click handler for each link.